# How to make a mouse popup box in Visual C# form?

Tags: c#, forms

I want an info message to pop up while you put your mouse on a button in the form (I want it to tell you what the button do) without you pressing on it.

example: when you put your mouse on the search in the bottom part of windows  10(maybe 8 ) and it tell you  " search the web and windows ".

thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a ToolTip?  It's a control that comes standard in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag a ToolTip object onto your design surface.  Then in the Form() function that is called on program execution, add lines like the following:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "This button does XYZ");
```

Comment: were ‫exactly i need to put the line ?? inside the private void _toolTipe1 ?

Comment: You should have a Form() method with InitializeComponent() inside of it.  Put the line I gave you -- or one like it that gives the tip you need on the control you specify -- below the InitializeComponent() line inside the Form() method.